# My cat jumped from the balcony!!

Tags: cats, behavior

my Bengal cat got out onto the balcony.  I didn't even know he got out.  The next morning we couldn't find him in the house and I remembered I had the door open to the balcony for 10 minutes.  We went to look for him and found him in the front under bushes.  This was Saturday morning and it's Monday afternoon now.  He's eating a little and keeps licking his paws.  He walks fine and can jump.  He just isn't the same.  He's not playful, no more crazy zooming sessions. He used to meow when I got home and greet me at the door.  I know when cats get stressed it takes a day or 2 to get better but it's day 3.  I have an apt. with the vet for tomorrow just in case.  thanks!

Comment: Hi Mary! Can you clarify your question? What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

Taking him to the vet to have a check is always a good idea after a bad fall like that.

Until then what you can do is gently check for any unusual hardness in the soft tissue, especially around the stomach. Don't put too much pressure on it, though. Also keep an eye on whether it seems painful.

Then you can gently put some pressure on the joints, especially the legs, by holding them in your hand and just kind of gently apply a little bit of pressure. What you are looking for is a pain response, or any unusual lumps. Do the same for the entire legs to check for lumps, pain response, or possible breaks.

Next is the neck and spine, gently running your fingers along the top and sides from ears to tail (can easily be done with three fingers fairly quickly), then along tail by simply running it through your hand.

Also check the mobility of the joints (wrists, knees and shoulder/hips), mainly if there is any pain response (be extra careful here, it's both uncomfortable, and has the highest chance of making any damage worse). And along the ribcage and jaw, again looking for lumps or pain responses. And lastly checking the skull for lumps, damage, fractures, or pain.

It is **very** important to be gentle, you shouldn't need to use much if any pressure. This should avoid making any injuries worse, and will help your vet when you drop by.

Do keep in mind that pain is something cats are naturally conditioned to hide, so signs can be subtle. But you should note a reluctance to be touched in painful areas, signs of discomfort or annoyance.

Note: This is stuff you should be doing regularly on your pet, for example very discreetly during cuddling sessions. It will keep you familiar with how your pet should feel, and will alert you early to most issues that are common in cats. This will also give you a very good baseline to determine if any reaction to touch is just annoyance, or if it's painful.